# WYSIWYG HTML editor for grails gsp files

Tags: html, grails, wysiwyg, gsp

Does anyone know about a good HTML editor which can be configured in such a way that it is gsp aware?
What I mean is that at least tags such as `<g:link>` and `<g:input>` should be displayed as their html equivalent.

Yes I know: a perfect editor is hard to write and it is easier to edit the HTML sources (that's what I do), but there are people who prefer an HTML editor...

**Update:** yes, I am looking for a WYSIWYG HTML editor with which I can drag'n'drop some html elements to a page without changing the `<g:...>` tags which might already be contained in the page. In addition, this editor should have some gsp awareness, so that `<g:...>` tags are displayed in an appropriate way.

**Update:** still looking for something, so I started a bounty. What I need is something like this plugin: http://code.google.com/p/grails-form-builder-plugin/ but more evolved...

**Bounty:** not easy to select the right answer for the bounty. None of the answers is a solution to my problem, but I have decided that rschlachter points me in the right direction: a wysiwyg form editor is not the right solution for a developer...

Comment: I can recommend intellJ. The grails development in this IDE maks fun. And the editor recognizes gsp tags and can work with groovy. I know this is not free but it worth.

Comment: Please explain what is the context of your question? Is that an editor to edit application or an editor to use in an application? I don't understand why you want <g:link> to be displayed as HTML equivalent?

Comment: I would like to edit the design of .gsp pages. Someone without much HTML knowledge should be able to visually design a form or a screen. A simple HTML editor is great for a start, but as soon as it comes to a roundtrip (editing the html which has already some gsp tag in it), a normal html editor will not work.

Comment: so you're asking solely for a WYSIWYG html editor?

Comment: yep. IMHO, an XML editor or even a plain text editor is enough for editing gsp sources. But some people need something to drag'n'drop some form fields, images and other elements to a view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there may be a flaw in the process here. You could build the page first in HTML and make any changes there before putting in any gsp elements. While the page is in HTML format people can continue to use WYSIWYG editors and then developers can add in the grails functionality.

It just seems like if you need/want to use a WYSIWYG editor, you shouldn't be modifying a gsp.

The iterations I prefer to use after I have gathered requirements are:

1. wireframe
2. mockup
3. html
4. gsp

If the gsps are already there (ie you inherited the project or something) you could go back a step and create an html only version of the page by pulling the gsp elements out and putting in images of them or replacing them with their html equivalents.

Comment: Hm. You are right and I do think the same way. But there are developers which are used to MS Access, visual disign of java dialogs or other MS Visua  Studio tools which (afaik) are even capable of doing this wysiwyg editing for dynamic asp pages. I need a way to empower those non-HTML developers to create basic forms...

Answer (score 2):

the IBM Maqetta Project seems to be going in the right direction:

http://maqetta.org/

Answer (score 1):

Mercury editor might be worth looking at too.
http://jejacks0n.github.com/mercury/

There is one more editor that you might want to look at:

- Aloha Editor - http://www.aloha-editor.org/

Comment: two great HTML5 editors - thank you for the links. But I doubt that they will be of great help with grails :-/

Answer (score 1):

Orbeon can be an option
http://www.orbeon.com/orbeon/home/

Answer (score 1):

Might be able to do this with TinyMCE by configuring the `valid_elements` or the `extended_valid_elements` ([docs](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements)). For example, if you want to replace `<g:link>` and `<g:input>` you would do something like:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    valid_elements : "a/g:link,input/g:input"
});
```

**OR** If you want to simply enable the additional elements, then you could do something like:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    extended_valid_elements : "g:link,g:input"
});
```

Comment: Nice trick and good to know. But it will not display those fields correctly..., will it?

Comment: @Ralf Might've misread the question. Updating for alternative possibility.

Comment: @Ralf I think TinyMCE can do this. Definitely, can if you write a plugin, but I think it will out of the box.